# Possible to prevent display of plugins in django-cms to users who don't have permissions for them?

Tags: django-cms

I've got several a restricted group of users who can only add/edit pages. I don't want them to have access to several plugins in django cms 2.2.

How can I prevent those plugins being displayed to users without permissions to u

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible in django CMS yet.